# R - Best practice for chaining data.table operations

Tags: r, data.table

Searched everywhere but didn't find any general guidelines for arranging data.table chained code that might be spanning multiple lines to improve readablility.

Take f.ex. (just toy examples for illustrative purposes)

```
iris.dt[sepal.length > 5 & sepal.width > 3 & petal.length > 2 & petal.width > 2 & species == "virginica"]
```

As this all corresponds to the same argument (dt[i]) splitting it over multiple lines is easy and I would simply do:

```
iris.dt[sepal.length > 5 & 
        sepal.width  > 3 & 
        petal.length > 2 & 
        petal.width  > 2 & 
        species == "virginica"]
```

or

```
iris.dt[sepal.length > 5 & 
          sepal.width  > 3 & 
          petal.length > 2 & 
          petal.width  > 2 & 
          species == "virginica"]
```

---

But take f.ex. sth like this. How would you clean up **this code snippet** and where would you indent / break lines? Note: It is just a toy example for what a long data.table chained code block could look like in practice.

```
    iris.dt[, id := 1:.N, by = species][, comb_area_sepal := (sepal.length * sepal.width), 
by = species][, comb_area_petal := (petal.length * petal.width), by = species][
species == "virginica" & comb_area_petal > 12.5, .(petal.width, petal.length, comb_area_petal]
```

How would I deal with such code? How best to break the lines and arrange arguements and brackets? What should I prioritize to **improve readability**?

Sometimes especially when handling large data sets and variable names (column names) are very long to be descriptive of some sort, the arguements (mostly j) will span several lines. Should I indent same arguments then if they span multiple lines (dt[i, j, by]). So indenting j on the second line onwards?

My intuition would break the above toy example like so:

```
    iris.dt[, id := 1:.N, by = species][,
            comb_area_sepal := (sepal.length * sepal.width), 
            by = species][, 
            comb_area_petal := (petal.length * petal.width), 
            by = species][
            species == "virginica" & comb_area_petal > 12.5,
            .(petal.width, petal.length, comb_area_petal]
```

What do you think? I realize that this might also differ among various different coding styles, but I am very much interested what concepts you apply in practice to keep such code easily readable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first operation of creating sequence can be simplified with `rowid`, then the second and third of creating two column by multiplication, doesn't really need group by as these are elementwise operations and can be combined together.  The last one is a subset (rows), select columns

```
iris.dt[, id := rowid(species)][,
    c('comb_area_sepal', 'comb_area_petal') := 
     .((sepal.length * sepal.width), (petal.length * petal.width))
      ][species == "virginica" & comb_area_petal > 12.5,
        .(petal.width, petal.length, comb_area_petal)]
```

---

Also, this can be chained with `%>%`

```
library(magrittr)
iris.dt[, id := rowid(species)] %>%
    .[,c('comb_area_sepal', 'comb_area_petal') := 
     .((sepal.length * sepal.width), (petal.length * petal.width))
      ] %>%
    .[species == "virginica" & comb_area_petal > 12.5,
        .(petal.width, petal.length, comb_area_petal)]
```

-output

```
#     petal.width petal.length comb_area_petal
# 1:         2.5          6.0           15.00
# 2:         2.2          5.8           12.76
# 3:         2.1          6.6           13.86
# 4:         2.5          6.1           15.25
# 5:         2.2          6.7           14.74
# 6:         2.3          6.9           15.87
# 7:         2.3          5.7           13.11
# 8:         2.0          6.7           13.40
# 9:         2.0          6.4           12.80
#10:         2.3          6.1           14.03
#11:         2.4          5.6           13.44
#12:         2.4          5.6           13.44
#13:         2.3          5.9           13.57
#14:         2.5          5.7           14.25
```

---

For the first case, it can be simplified as well

```
iris.dt[iris.dt[, Reduce(`&`, Map(`>`,.SD, .(5, 3, 2, 2))) & 
     species == 'virginica', .SDcols = sepal.length:petal.width]]
```

Comment: Great trick! And easily implemented! Thanks.

But how about aligning code besides your suggestions. Especially if you assign this data.table operation as an intermediate result to a variable and store it for later tasks, I feel that the code generally becomes "messy" in the sense that you cannot easily distinguish what part of the code belongs to which of a data.table's arguments, i.e.  ```dt[i, j, by]```

Comment: I didn't know that! So you can chain data.table chained code using ```%>%``` the dpylr pipe command and then ```.[  ]``` to continue where you left off at the previous data.table operation?

Comment: @aimbotter21 You can do the chaining.  But, please remember that when you do the `:=`, it is transforming the original object as these are in place assignment compared to `mutate` in dplyr

Comment: @aimbotter21 I understand your vision of trying to chain etc.  But, IMHO, `data.table` and `dplyr` are two different concepts.  So, should be careful when there is a side-effect in some operations.  I use `dplyr` mainly during development and testing

Comment: Awesome! Not directly what I was looking for, but your answer exceeds my expactions for improving readability by far. Defintely a better way to clean up code this way. Thanks!

Comment: I do have one more question though going a bit off topic. I imported a .csv file with ```fread()```. Some data is of type character and should be transformed to type ```Date```. I wrote a function for performing this task over and over again (basically bringing character based dates to the date format ```%Y-%m-%d```. How can I define the columns that the function should be applied to in a similar fashion as you did by saying ```dt[, c("var1", "var2", "var3") := .(some_function with all columns as input parameter]```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228676/discussion-between-aimbotter21-and-akrun).